# Early exercise premium with discrete cash dividends using integral approximation

Tags: options, american-options

From my understanding, we have to integrate $N(d1(S_x-D,B,t))$ on both asset-price and time-space  to derive the Early Exercise Premium $EEP(B,t)$ on each $t$ before the ex-date to get current early exercise premium $EEP(S,0)$. Where
$$S_x = S  \exp((r-\sigma^2/2)  t + x  \sigma  \sqrt{t})$$ Is this correct?

When I use carry and vol backed out from European option prices, continuous div EEP is at bid of American quotes, which is correct. But when I use discrete cash div version EEP is a fraction of the continuous one, which takes American price below payoff which is wrong. I apply the same method on backing out carry with discrete div which only returns implied borrow/lending fee that I use to plug in as q.

Thanks.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251443198_The_early_exercise_premium_for_American_put_options_on_stocks_with_dividends

---

[image: EEB for div yield]
[image: Call EEB for fixed cash div]